# Solution set of inequalities in $\mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Let $\theta\in (0,1)$ fixed.
We define $A_1$ be the set of all $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)\in (0,1)^6$ such that the following conditions hold:

\begin{equation}
(1)  \quad a_2\le a_1, a_4\le a_3, a_6 \le a_5, a_5>a_3, \text{ and } a_2>\theta.
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
(2) \quad  a_2(a_5-a_3)=a_1(a_2-\theta)
\end{equation}
We define $A_2$ be the set of all $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)\in \mathbb{R}^6$ such that
the condition $(1)$ is satisfied and the following conditions hold:
\begin{equation}
a_4\le \theta \text{ and } (a_2+a_4-\theta)a_1=a_2a_5.
\end{equation}
Note that, for $\theta=\frac{1}{5}$ we have 
$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{15},\frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{5})\in A_1$ but 
$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{15},\frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{5})\notin A_2$.
and also
$(\frac{3}{7},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{7}, \frac{1}{3})\in A_2$ but 
$(\frac{3}{7},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{7}, \frac{1}{3})\notin A_1$.
Thus, we can not conclude that $A_1\subset A_2$ or $A_2 \subset A_1$.

Since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the subsets of unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^6$, the volume of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are finite.

My question is that could one compare the volume of $A_1$ and $A_2$?

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Just condition (2) by itself forces the six-dimensional volume to be $0$. (For every $a_2,\dots,a_6$, there's at most one $a_1$ that makes (2) work.) Similarly with the multiplicative identity characterizing $A_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by volume?

Comment: @GregMartin I don't see why the volume must be zero, since equation (2) doesn't contain $a_6$.

Comment: @MichaelKasa $\dim(A_1)=5$ and $\dim(\mathbb{R}^6)=6$

Comment: The sketch of why the volume must be zero is independent of whether the equation contains any single variable. The same argument applies, for example, to the parabolic sheet $a_3=a_5^2$ in $\Bbb R^6$: for every $a_1,a_2,a_4,a_5,a_6\in\Bbb R$, there is exactly one $a_3$ that satisfies the equation, and that's enough to make the volume zero.